# String comparison in Ruby on Rails unit-test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, string

my Ruby On Rails unit-test fails in a simple string comparison and I can't figure out why.

In the model `TestItem`, I have

```
doc = REXML::Document.new(data)
@bugtitle = doc.root.get_text("/bugzilla/bug/short_desc")
```

where data is a xml-string returned by a `Net::HTTP::post` request. The data looks good, and if I output `@bugtitle` it contains the expected string. In my unit-test, I have

```
  test "bugtitle" do
    ti = testitems(:one)
    assert_equal("different RID folder for gating x-ray correction images",ti.bugtitle)
  end
```

Surprisingly (at least for me) the test fails with the following output (copied verbatim from the shell):

```
  1) Failure:
 test_bugtitle(TestTest) [unit/testitem_test.rb:7]:
 <"different RID folder for gating x-ray correction images"> expected but was
 <"different RID folder for gating x-ray correction images">.
```

I'm at a loss here as to where this error comes from since the string do look identical to me. For what it's worth, this is with rails 2.3.4 and ruby 1.8.6 on Windows (don't get me started).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since MBO poked me into the right direction, here is the solution:

For debugging, I added a `p @bugtitle.class` into the model code, which revealed, that `@bugtitle` was an `REXML::Text` instance. The correct model code is:

```
doc = REXML::Document.new(data)
@bugtitle = doc.root.get_text("/bugzilla/bug/short_desc").to_s
```

With that modification the unit-test completes without failures.

Answer (score 1):

Those two seems identical, but you only see their representation after `#inspect`. You should check encoding and binary representation (if it's Ruby 1.9), maybe that's the problem.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to #inspect, which didn't help in itself, but got me curious. See my answer for the solution.